Why were US businessmen in the late 19th cent. known >in print< by first & middle initial + last name, such as R.N. Smith?
I am researching an area of interest in the late 19th century in the United States.  I have encountered many men's names in print by first initial, middle initial and surname when being referred to in a business sense or in a newspaper article.  It took me a few years to learn the full name of someone I've been researching, whose name first appeared in the form of (not his real name) "R.N. Smith" in an 1898 news article, and later on everything he wrote!  This was common usage in business at the time (and a complete pain when trying to follow an old genealogical trail!), and I am wondering the reason(s) for it.  Did "R.N. Smith" hint of a certain kind of importance or status?  Was this usage thought to give the company name a "big" sound, even if one person was the company?  Or something else?  Thank you.

Why do you think this is unusual? Many people go by their initials and surname in business today.

What's important to know about newspapers is that composing type used to be manual. Newspapers abbreviated heavily to keep articles short and control the cost of paper, ink, and labor. Even when they weren't abbreviating John to J. they were abbreviating it to Jno. Also, it was common at that time to refer to people using surnames. So "Smith" is what you might know him as, so his given name was less relevant, even in print.

This article by Ian Scott for the National Library of Scotland is relevant (I've bolded major reasons put forward):

Initial success : J. R. Hartley and other authors who use initials                                                                                                           27th March 2023  Ian Scott
In 1983 the best-known author in Britain
was not a bestseller like Jeffrey Archer, Roald Dahl, or Fay Weldon
but J.R. Hartley the author of “Fly fishing”. The book was featured in
an advert promoting the Yellow Pages telephone directory. “Fly
fishing” was the object of a quest round second-hand bookshops by an
elderly gentleman. In each shop he would ask if they had a copy of
“Fly fishing” by J.R. Hartley only to get the answer no, and with each
no he became a more dejected figure. His daughter suggests instead of
trudging round bookshops he phones them using Yellow Pages. The advert
ends with him on the phone to a bookseller who has a copy. “You do,
that’s wonderful. My name … J.R. Hartley.” Mission accomplished and he
was looking for his own book!
J.R. Hartley and his elusive book did not exist of course and were
created by an advertising agency. Copy for an advert is endlessly
revised and it is no accident they decided on an author’s name
featuring initials. They knew that using initials can do many things
including add a touch of mystery, a patina of literary authority, even
a little magic. It places an author in a tradition that includes many
of the most celebrated authors of all time including D. H. Lawrence,
J. D. Salinger, T. S. Eliot, J. R. R. Tolkien and E.M. Forster. Among
the many contemporary writers who have chosen to publish under
initials are J.K. Rowling and E.L. James . We researched writers who
published under initials whilst working on the Library’s exhibition
‘Pen Name” and discovered that authors had a variety of reasons for
choosing to use initials.
Trinidadian-born brothers V.S. and Shiva Naipaul both became
successful writers after emigrating to Britain. V.S. Naipaul chose to
use initials rather than his full name Vidiadhar Surajprasad Naipaul.
As well as being difficult to fit on a book cover his full name would
likely have been frequently misspelled and mispronounced. His older
brother already having dibs on the use of initials, Shivadhar
Srinivasa Naipaul published under a shortened version of his first
given name.
The classic children’s novel “Anne of Green Gables” was published as
by L.M. Montgomery, not the author’s full name Lucy Maud Montgomery.
The author strongly disliked her first name Lucy and was generally
called Maud by family and friends. The best way to remove the hated
Lucy from her book covers was to use initials. Authors who hate their
names are in a minority, but some prefer to use initials simply
because it looks better. Clive Staples Lewis published his Narnia
stories and other books as C.S. Lewis and Jerome David Salinger author
of “The Catcher in the Rye” is known as J.D. Salinger. Clive Lewis and
Jerome Salinger are simply not as pleasing to the eye or the tongue as
C.S. Lewis and J.D. Salinger.
George Raymond Richard Martin is the author of a fantasy series which
was adapted into the television series “Game of thrones”. He publishes
as George R.R. Martin and has said that for an author your name is
your brand, so making it striking and unique is important. It also
usefully differentiates him from another famous George Martin, the
Beatles producer. The double R.R. recalls J.R.R Tolkien the most
celebrated and influential fantasy author of the 20th century and so
acts both as a homage and a signal to readers that Martin is working
in the same literary tradition.
Alistair MacLean’s niece Shona MacLean is the author of a series of
successful historical thrillers, including the recent “The Bookseller
of Inverness”. Her first three novels were published as Shona MacLean,
but she published her fourth and subsequent books as S.G. MacLean.
This was at the suggestion of her publisher who thought her name was
too soft and feminine and might put male readers off. Market research
has shown that men (and boys) can be reluctant to read books by women,
and this explains in part why some women authors including J.K.
Rowling choose to use initials when they publish.
Alison Louise Kennedy publishes as A.L. Kennedy which she regards as a
pen name. She believes using her initials provides a necessary mental
place of safety from which to write. Using initials neatly
differentiates between Alison and the prize-winning literary novelist
A.L.
The magical English nanny Mary Poppins is the creation of an
Australian who was born Helen Lyndon Goff, but published as P.L.
Travers. Goff took the name Pamela Travers when she acted with a
touring theatrical company that performed Shakespeare in Australia and
New Zealand. She continued to use Pamela Travers when she moved to
England and became a prolific journalist and poet. Goff wanted her
first book “Mary Poppins” published as by anonymous, but her publisher
was not happy with this, so P.L. Travers was used. The form chosen as
“it seemed to me at the time that all children’s book were written by
women, and I didn’t want to feel that there was a woman or a man
behind it, but a human being.”
In 1991 J.R. Hartley became a real author, or at least a book called
“Fly fishing: memories of angling days” by J.R. Hartley was published.
The book was in fact written by Michael Russell and became a
bestseller. Russell would use J.R. Hartley as a pen name for two
follow up fishing books. J.R. Hartley had caught the public’s
imagination, in part because of the copy writer’s wise decision to use
initials when naming their fictional author.
Authors use of initials is explored in the National Library of
Scotland’s exhibition Pen Names which explores a range of writers
working in Britain from the 1800s to the present day who use pen
names. The exhibition runs from 8 July 2022 to 29 April 2023. Learn
more about Pen Names on our website.


This way of presenting one's name is not uncommon in the UK and the countries whose culture is significantly UK-influenced, so its use there probably doesn't require this elaborate explanation. The quoted article, in any event, does not quite answer the question, which is specifically about the practice in the nineteenth century US. The OP is seeking an explanation of the practice at that time and place, against the background of its being rather uncommon in the present-day US.

Your first sentence reads rather like 'It's common because it's common.' // The overarching reasons given may well have informed the requested practice. 'They knew that using initials can do many things including add a touch of mystery, a patina of literary authority, even a little magic.' Wouldn't this be true in the then US business world as well as the later UK advertising world? I doubt whether any more authoritative sources will be found on the actual domain OP specifies.

Were those titles 'Fly fishing' , 'Game of thrones' presented thus (initial letter upper case, remainder lower case) in the original?

Of course not.  They're already catchier than say John Clegg (especially 'Fly Fishing').
